# How to create a right/left Background animation?

Tags: android, animation

I try to develop an application with a left/right animation on the background on the first screen.

For example, this [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist&hl=en) have an image in background and this image move from left to right. It's exactly what I want to do.

[image]

I try with this code :

```
ImageView imageViewBackground = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewBackground);

Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(5000);
imageViewBackground.startAnimation(animation);
```

and

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBackground"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

But the imageView with this scaleType are cropped and we can't see the content of the imageView entirely current the animation.

Comment: from left to right? why are you disturbing your mind Sir? do this `Animation animation = AnimationUtils(getBaseContext(),R.anim.slide_from_left_to_right);` that's all.. that `R.anim` is a default animation

Comment: I know how to anime ImageView from left to right. But here it's a specific problem with background imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [SlideImageView](https://github.com/GIGAMOLE/SlideImageView) library from the GitHub. It gives you what you want.